# error NG6003: 'CodemirrorModule' does not appear to be an NgModule

Tags: angular

how to resolve this issue

I tried to install npm i codemirrormodule but it does not works as expected.. but still i got this error

> Error: LC/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:214:5 - error NG6003:
> 'CodemirrorModule' does not appear to be an NgModule, Component,
> Directive, or Pipe class.
>
> 214     CodemirrorModule,